# Pure JavaScript Internal Promotions in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I've been tasked with creating a pure JS internal promotion tracker and implementing this via GTM. I'm not sure if I've done it in a very convoluted way or not so open to any suggestions!

At the moment I have the following tags:

This function checks that an element, referenced later, is in the viewport

```
  function isInViewport(element) {
  var rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var html = document.documentElement;
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || html.clientHeight) &&
    rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || html.clientWidth)
  );
}
```

I then grab all of the elements on the page that I want to check are in view, and push these into an array.

This is the script I'm using to do that. N.B. I've performed modulus division on the list as there are other items on the page that satisfy that selector however I only want to select each 5th item.

```
var id = document.getElementById('foo');
var list = id.getElementsByTagName('ba');
var items = [];
var position = [];
var j = 1;


for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (i % 5 == 0) {

        items.push(list[i]);
        j = j + 1;
    }
}
```

I then want to check if each of these elements are in the users viewport as they scroll while building an ecommerce object to be pushed to the dataLayer using the following script:

```
window.onscroll = myfunction;
var ecommerceObject;
var event;
function myfunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (isInViewport(list[i]) === true) {
            ecommerceObject['ecommerce']['promoView'] = {
              'event' : 'promoview',  
              'promotions': [{
                    'id': items[i].innerText.split("\n")[1],
                    'name': items[i].id
                }]
                             };
            window.dataLayer.push(ecommerceObject);
        }
    }

}
```

My issue at the moment is that whenever I scroll I am repeatedly checking all items that satisfy my selector meaning that until an item isn't in the viewport anymore I will get the same item pushed to the dataLayer multiple times.

Is there anyway that I can:

A - Stop having the same item pushed to the dataLayer each time the user scrolls and only have it pushed once

B - Condense my code so that it's not in three separate scripts

Thanks a lot for taking the time to look over this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) you can use a boolean to detect if dataLayer push has been execued as below:

```
window.onscroll = myfunction;
var ecommerceObject;
var event;
var done = false; // example of a new variable 
function myfunction() {
    for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (isInViewport(list[i]) === true && !done) { //execute only if NOT done
            done = true; //set done to true
            ecommerceObject['ecommerce']['promoView'] = {
              'event' : 'promoview',  
              'promotions': [{
                    'id': items[i].innerText.split("\n")[1],
                    'name': items[i].id
                }]
                             };
            window.dataLayer.push(ecommerceObject);
        }
    }

}
```

B) What is the reason you have it in 3 separate scripts on the first place?